# Setting UINavigationController Frame Does Not Alter Appearance

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Alright, so I have a UINavigationController and I'm setting its frame in my viewDidLoad.

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 586, 44)];
```

Once the view loads, the NavigationController is still at its full width of `1024`.

**When the view appears:**[image]

Not until I `push` something onto the Navigation Controller does it update its frame to be `586`.

**After a push or pop:**[image]

Note : calling `[... setNeedsDisplay];` doesn't do the trick and neither does `[... setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingNone];`

Any thoughts on why it is not like this initially or on how to redraw it?

Comment: Have you tried resizing it in viewWillAppear: instead of viewDidLoad?

Comment: @KevinHorgan — Unfortunately I've already tried this approach. Doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: Well first your actually re-sizing the frame of the navigation controller's navigation bar, not the controller itself. I think you may want to resize the navigation controller's views.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can't change the frame directly you should customize the navigationBar